# Error when subtracting columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query I'm using to attempt to get a date difference by subtracting values between two columns. Here is part of this query:

```
SELECT
ISNULL(MIN(c.CreatedOn), 0) AS [StartDate], 
ISNULL(MIN(s.CreatedOn), 0) AS [EndDate],
Duration = [EndDate]-[StartDate]
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN...
```

The error that I am receiving states that I have Invalid Column Names.
Is it possible to write the query this way?

Comment: You have accepted an answer very quickly and this may discourage more high quality answers from being posted. Wait a day or two and see what quality answers you might get, the accepted answer is correct, but does not cover the best solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously defined column aliases can't be used in the same query. Use the actual calculation instead.

```
SELECT
ISNULL(MIN(c.CreatedOn), 0) AS [StartDate], 
ISNULL(MIN(s.CreatedOn), 0) AS [EndDate],
Duration = ISNULL(MIN(s.CreatedOn), 0)-ISNULL(MIN(c.CreatedOn), 0)
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN...
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aliases within the same query.  If you must use them, then you can use a nested query, or a `WITH` statement.

**Nested Query**

```
Select StartDate, EndDate,
       Duration = [EndDate]-[StartDate]
From
(
    SELECT
    ISNULL(MIN(c.CreatedOn), 0) AS [StartDate], 
    ISNULL(MIN(s.CreatedOn), 0) AS [EndDate]
    FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN...
) InnerQuery
```

**WITH statement**

```
;With InnerQuery AS
(
    SELECT
    ISNULL(MIN(c.CreatedOn), 0) AS [StartDate], 
    ISNULL(MIN(s.CreatedOn), 0) AS [EndDate]
    FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN...
) 
Select StartDate, EndDate,
       Duration = [EndDate]-[StartDate]
From InnerQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a [datediff function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
select datediff(day, min('12/01/2014'), min(getdate()))
```

P.S., What are you expecting when you isnull a date data type to an int?

```
select isnull(cast(null as date), 0)
```